# should I use an object to handle user search criteria?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a search form that allows users to search real estate listings. 
I currently have it set up as a basic html form that posts to a search results page.
On the search results page, I then use raw SQL and query the database and then use a repeater to display the results. I also create session variables on the query so if the user does another search they dont have to fill out the whole search, just edit it.

I was wondering if I should rather create a search class with a search object that gets created and edited with each search. Is this the best practice? or is my method above sufficient?
Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

If there are lots of search parameters then I'd create a class to encapsulate them all and store that in session state, rather than maintaining lots of separate session variables. You might need to decorate this class with the `SerializableAttribute` depending on how you've got your session state configured, e.g.

```
[Serializable]
public class SearchOptions
{
    public string Foo { get; set; }
    public string Bar { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: thanks,I have between 5 and 8 fields for search criteria. So I think I will just leave it as it is...